# LaTeX does not print words correctly: inputenc/fontenc problem

Tags: font-encodings, input-encodings

I'm using a MacBook Pro and TeXShop. I am writing a philosophy thesis and fairly new to LaTeX.

In my preamble I have put

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage[francais,english]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=FitV, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{12}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}

 These earlier ﬁrms, were far more powerful; they commanded armies and ﬂeets

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblio.bib}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

However, in the pdf I get: 
"These earlier rms, were far more powerful; they commanded armies and eets"

Also, I want to use french characters (i.e. é è ç ô ê, etc), but I still have to type 
    `e 
and so on.

I have googled, and played a bit with `[latin1]` but don't find an answer; please help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I've removed the second question because here it's best to have only one question per topic, in order to keep the site more easily informative. Feel free to add a new question. Can you add more to that code bit? A minimal part of your code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Could you post a Minimal Working Example?

Comment: I hope this can be seen as a MWE. Sorry, but I'm very new to this.

Comment: You need to check the settings in your editor. Give `applemac` a go, that is usually the default in `TeXShop`, though I'd recommend reconfiguring it to use 'utf8`, might be better when exchanging documents with others.

Comment: I tried applemac as a package, but didn't work. In my editor preferences, I put encoding to `utf8', but to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use the `ﬁ` and `ﬂ` characters in the input, but write `firms` and `fleets`.

Also add the following "magic" line at the beginning of your file

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
```

This will ensure that TeXShop interprets your file as UTF-8.

If your text has already many instances of `ﬁ` and `ﬂ`, you can consider adding the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ﬁ}{fi}
\newunicodechar{ﬂ}{fl}
```

but it's best to stick with normal input.

Accented characters will be treated correctly.

Here's an example:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage[francais,english]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=FitV, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{12}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ﬁ}{fi}
\newunicodechar{ﬂ}{fl}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

 These earlier firms, were far more powerful; they commanded armies and fleets

 These earlier ﬁrms, were far more powerful; they commanded armies and ﬂeets

 Garçon, été, l'Hôpital, Génève

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblio.bib}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tried the "% !TEX line", but won't work. Also, I do write firms and fleets. So where does it go wrong?

Comment: @pieter Your code above shows that the ligatures are used. Perhaps you copy-pasted the code. Close and reopen the file.

Comment: Thanks, that code did work. So I guess that's because of the \newunicodechar ? Anything I can do to avoid this in a next document?

Comment: @pieter The normal behavior of TeXShop is *not* to use the special ligatures in the `.tex` document. As I said before, you probably pasted that text from some source. A PDF file? Just do a "search and replace" to change the special characters into `fi` and `fl`.

Comment: Indeed, that was a quote from a pdf file. Makes sense now :-). Thanks a lot!